# iphone jquery .on click code isn't clickable

Tags: jquery, iphone

Why doesn't this work on an iphone?

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-state-default', function(e) {
    $(".upload").show();
});
```

Am I missing something?

I'm using iOS 6.1 and jQuery 1.8.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', '.ui-state-default', function(e) {
    $(".upload").show();
});
```

Click sometimes doesn't work on iOS devices like iPad, etc. In such cases you need to use, either `touchstart`, `touchend` or `touchmove`.